# Как ускорить цикл for для обхода массива?

Tags: python, numpy, оптимизация, производительность, scipy

Есть два массива. Двумя циклами `for` обхожу первый массив, на основании данных из которого, заполняю второй. При больших размерах массива программа выполняется очень долго.

Подскажите методы ускорения обхода массива с использованием стандартных инструментов, или например numpy.

```
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)

array = np.full((img.shape[0], img.shape[1], 3), black, dtype='uint8')

for i in range (img.shape[0]):
    for j in range (img.shape[1]): 
        if (img[i, j] == True):
            array[i, j, :] = white
```

Comment: Укажите пожалуйста форму (`shape`) массивов: `img` и `array`

Comment: т.к. значения `array` не зависят от предыдущих (следующих) шагов, то возможно распараллеливание, например индексы массива будут перебирать 4 потока (так чтобы индексы не пересекались), тогда массив `array` быстрее заполнится

Comment: Суть задачи сводится к тому, чтобы на основании массива img (содержит true/false, форма - (x, y)) заполнить массив array (форма - (x, y, 3)) кортежами white/black.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
array[np.nonzero(img)] = white
```

или еще красивее и быстрее ([как посоветовал @jfs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/602870/python-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb-for/602901#comment818256_602901)):

```
arr[img != 0] = white
```

вместо всего цикла

Demo:

```
In [169]: %paste
arr = np.arange(27).reshape(3,3,3)
img = np.array([[0,1,0],
                [0,0,0],
                [0,0,1]])

expected = arr.copy()

for i in range(img.shape[0]):
    for j in range(img.shape[1]):
        if img[i, j]:
            expected[i, j, :] = 100
## -- End pasted text --
```

Оригинальный массив:

```
In [170]: arr
Out[170]:
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]],

       [[18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26]]])
```

Ожидаемый массив:

```
In [171]: expected
Out[171]:
array([[[  0,   1,   2],
        [100, 100, 100],
        [  6,   7,   8]],

       [[  9,  10,  11],
        [ 12,  13,  14],
        [ 15,  16,  17]],

       [[ 18,  19,  20],
        [ 21,  22,  23],
        [100, 100, 100]]])

In [172]: arr == expected
Out[172]:
array([[[ True,  True,  True],
        [False, False, False],
        [ True,  True,  True]],

       [[ True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True]],

       [[ True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True],
        [False, False, False]]], dtype=bool)
```

используя NumPy индексирование:

```
In [173]: arr[np.nonzero(img)] = 100
```

Проверка:

```
In [174]: (arr == expected).all()
Out[174]: True
```

Сравнение производительности:

```
In [1]: %paste
arr = np.random.randint(0,255,(10**4,10**4,3))
img = np.random.choice([True, False], (arr.shape[0], arr.shape[1]))

## -- End pasted text --

In [5]: arr.shape
Out[5]: (10000, 10000, 3)

In [6]: img.shape
Out[6]: (10000, 10000)

In [7]: %timeit arr[np.nonzero(img)]
1 loop, best of 3: 6.28 s per loop

In [8]: %timeit arr[img != 0, :]
1 loop, best of 3: 5.5 s per loop
```

Comment: можно явно с нулём сравнить: `arr[img != 0] = 100` (чтобы показать [как другие условия добавить](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3030480/4279)). Чтобы узнать равны ли массивы `np.all(arr==expected)` или `np.allclose(arr, expected)` для float значений.

Comment: @jfs, спасибо!!  так выглядит лучше и проще, но я не уверен, что не будет небольшого проигрыша в производительности - надо потестировать на больших массивах

Comment: @jfs, сравнил производительность для массивов размерностью (10000, 10000, 3) - ваш вариант быстрее и понятнее выглядит!